# ios Can not find memory leak in viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, memory-management, memory-leaks

In my iOS Swift app,

I have a WKWebView in my view controller. when I am push and pop the view controller WebView is not being deallocated, it remains in the memory.

I checked in my memory debugger graph, but not able to recognise which objects needs to deallocate.
[image]

I use to nil references, in viewWillDisapper method

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        if self.isMovingFromParent {
            print("view controller is popped")
            self.pdfWebView?.configuration.userContentController.removeScriptMessageHandler(forName: "jsMessageHandler")
            self.pdfWebView?.configuration.userContentController.removeScriptMessageHandler(forName: "generatePDF")
            self.generateWebView = nil
            self.account = nil
            self.recording = nil
            self.viewOptionECGQuality = nil
            self.storage = nil
            self.doctor = nil
            self.patient = nil
        }
    }
```

Please guide, if you have any suggestions